# Как нормализовать от пустых значений и ключей

Tags: php, массивы

а вот содержимое

между значениями новая пустая строка пробел и опять пустышка

```
version = ‘1.3.15’



source.id = ‘1’



source.path = ‘some/path’



login.remember = ‘1’



login.name = ‘userName’



login.password = ‘password’



awful.layout = ‘split’



awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’
```

вот код

```
$lines = file_get_contents('file.txt',  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
//разбиваем файловую строку по строкам
echo $lines;
$resLines = explode("\n",$lines);
//наш результирующий массив
    $resArray = array();
//по всем строкам
foreach($resLines as $resLineValue)
{
    //разбиваем на правую и левую часть выражение
    $resLine = explode("=", $resLineValue);
    $name = $resLine[0];
    $value = $resLine[1];

    //Выделяем массив значений имён.
    $names = explode(".",$name);
    //устанавливаем указатель на начало нашего массива
    $resWriter = &$resArray;
    //находим элемент хеша в который надо положить значение
    if(is_array($names))
    {
        foreach($names as $separate)
        {
            //если нету нужного имени в хеше, создаём его.
            if(!isset($resWriter[$separate]))
                $resWriter[$separate] = array();

            $resWriter = &$resWriter[$separate];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $resWriter = &$resWriter[$names];
    }
    //Устанавливаем значение.
    $resWriter = $value;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

вот вывод

```
Array
(
    [version ] =>  ‘1.3.15’
    [
] => 
    [ 
] => 
    [source] => Array
        (
            [id ] =>  ‘1’
            [path ] =>  ‘some/path’
        )

    [login] => Array
        (
            [remember ] =>  ‘1’
            [name ] =>  ‘userName’
            [password ] =>  ‘password’
        )

    [awful] => Array
        (
            [layout ] =>  ‘split’
            [layout] => Array
                (
                    [suit ] =>  ‘tile’
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file_get_contents не принимает таких ключей. Обратитесь к документации.

Команда file - да. Таким образом, если слегка преобразовать код вначале, то все работает как и задумывалось:

```
$resLines = file('file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

////разбиваем файловую строку по строкам
//echo $lines;
//
//$resLines = explode("\n", $lines);
```